# .remove() not working in android google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

While working on Google maps API V2 in an android application I want to have two markers one for source and one for destination. I set the global reference to both the markers and when I move to some other location and remove the destination marker using `destinationMarker.remove()` its not working for me. It doesn't deleting the previous marker.

**Code:**

```
//Global references
    Marker sourceMarker;
    Marker destinationMarker;
    ... 
    ...
    public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException{
        hideSoftKeyBoard(v);
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String Location = et.getText().toString();
        if(Location.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please specify a Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(Location, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();
        gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        if(destinationMarker != null){
         //removing marker if exists
            destinationMarker.remove();
        }
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title(locality).position(new LatLng(lat,lng));
        destinationMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);

    }
```

Comment: Try with `mMap.clear();`

Comment: I don't want to clear my other marker i.e. sourceMarker

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not working because you are removing the marker before adding it and giving a reference to it using the `addMarker(..)` method. Please remove the maker once it has been referenced using the `addmarker(..)` method.

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().title(locality).position(new LatLng(lat,lng));
        destinationMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
 if(destinationMarker != null){
         //removing marker if exists
            destinationMarker.remove();
        }

    }
```